# javascript addition program displaying "NaN" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is about this simple program always displaying a "NaN" error.

My code for this simple function will always alert a "NaN" error for a simple addition instruction and I'm not sure how to resolve this.

The program should simply add miles and the bonus, which is 1000 if `futureTrips` is any value greater than 0.

My code is:

```
    var miles;
    var futureTrips;
    var totalMiles;
    var bonus;
    miles = prompt("Please enter your current miles");
    futureTrips = prompt("pleae enter amount of future trips");

    if (futureTrips > 0){
        (bonus = 1000);}
    else{
        (bonus = 0);}

   totalMiles = (bonus.value + miles.value);
   alert(totalMiles);
```

This will always display a "NaN" error.  Any tips on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

`bonus` and `miles` are numbers (`miles` in fact is a string). You have to use them not their `.value` property that doesn't exist (thus is `undefined`), so:

```
totalMiles = (bonus.value + miles.value);
```

is the same as:

```
totalMiles = (undefined + undefined);
```

which is `NaN`.

---

**Fix:**

Use `bonus` and `miles` directly (you still have to convert `miles` to a number though):

```
totalMiles = bonus + Number(miles);
```

---

**Working snippett:**

```js
var miles;
var futureTrips;
var totalMiles;
var bonus;

miles = prompt("Please enter your current miles");
futureTrips = prompt("pleae enter amount of future trips");

futureTrips = Number(futureTrips);

if (futureTrips > 0) {
  bonus = 1000;
} else {
  bonus = 0;
}

totalMiles = bonus + Number(miles);
alert(totalMiles);
```

---

**Notes:**

1. `prompt` return strings, so you have to convert `miles` into a number first, otherwise you get a string concatenation instead of arithmitic addition. You don't have to convert `bonus` because it's already a number. You should also consider converting `futureTrips` to a number before the `if`.
2. Parenthesis are not necessary around expressions: `(bonus = 1000);` is equivalent to `bonus = 1000;`.

Answer (score 1):

In `JavaScript`, `prompt` returns `string` value. You can not apply `.value` on them. 
By default `string` values are converted to `int` before the addition with another integer (also known as coercing). But to be on the safe side you can use `parseInt` to convert `string` to `int` manually.

Change `totalMiles = (bonus.value + miles.value);` To

`totalMiles = (bonus.value + parseInt(miles));`

Comment: `bonus` and `miles` are numbers not inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var totalMiles;
var bonus;

var miles = parseInt(prompt("Please enter your current miles"),10);
var futureTrips = parseInt(prompt("pleae enter amount of future trips"),10);

if (futureTrips > 0) {
  bonus = 1000;
} else {
  bonus = 0;
}

totalMiles = bonus + miles;
alert(totalMiles);
```

I always use the radix in `parseInt` like `paarseInt(miles,10)`. Or use `parseFloat(miles)`.

Also don't use `bonus.value` or `miles.value`, just use `miles` since `miles` is the return string from then `prompt` command and `bonus` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code modified:

```
    var miles;
    var futureTrips;
    var totalMiles;
    var bonus;

    do{
        miles =  prompt("Please enter your current miles") ; //assigns a string value to variable
        futureTrips = prompt("pleae enter amount of future trips");

        miles = parseInt(miles);                //convert string to number
        futureTrips = parseInt(futureTrips);
    }while( isNaN(miles + futureTrips) );       //optional loop, repeat prompts if NaN detected 

    if (futureTrips > 0){
        (bonus = 1000);}
    else{
        (bonus = 0);}

   totalMiles = (bonus + miles);                // removed bonus.value, did you mean to use the Object.ValueOf() method?
   alert(totalMiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

`miles` is a string here. To get the value as an integer I suggest instead of `miles.value` do `parseInt(miles)`