# Why does one of these calculations return NaN when the others work as expected?

Tags: javascript

```js
var fir=prompt("Enter first Number");
var sec=prompt("Enter second number");
var sum=Number(fir)+Number(sec);
alert("The sum is " + sum);
alert("The difference is " + fir-sec);
alert("The product is " + fir*sec);
alert("The division is " + fir/sec);
```

Now: suppose fir=2 and sec=1.

The output is:

```
3
NaN
2
2
```

Why is the difference `NaN` instead of 1?

Comment: Add brackets + `alert("The Difference is " + (fir-sec));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript addition program displaying "NaN" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734987/javascript-addition-program-displaying-nan-error)

Comment: Because [type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

`*` and `/` have higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `+` and `-`, just like with PEMDAS order of operations in standard math. Specifically, `+` and `-` have precedence 13, whereas `*` and `/` have precedence 14.

When an expression has `+` and `-`s only, they're evaluated in [left-to-right order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table). So, your code is equivalent to:

```
alert(("The Difference is " + fir) - sec);
alert("The product is " + (fir*sec));
alert("The division is " + (fir/sec));
```

In the second and third `alert`, `fir` and `sec` get combined into a single numeric expression before being concatenated with the prior string.

In the first `alert`, `"The Difference is " + fir` get put together first, resulting in another string (a string `+` a number results in another string). So then you have

```
alert((someString) - sec);
```

But `someString - sec` doesn't make sense - you can't subtract something from a string, so the expression resolves to `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing

```
var fir=prompt("ENter 1st Number");
var sec=prompt("Enter second number");
var sum=Number(fir)+Number(sec);
var sub=Number(fir)-Number(sec);
alert("The Sum is " + sum);
alert("The Difference is " + sub);
alert("The product is " + fir*sec);
alert("The division is " + fir/sec);
```

Usually, the plus operator + sums numbers.

But, if the binary + is applied to strings, it merges (concatenates) them:

let s = "my" + "string";
alert(s); // mystring
Note that if one of the operands is a string, the other one is converted to a string too.

For example:

```
alert( '1' + 2 ); // "12"
alert( 2 + '1' ); // "21"
```

See, it doesn’t matter whether the first operand is a string or the second one. The rule is simple: if either operand is a string, the other one is converted into a string as well.

However, note that operations run from left to right. If there are two numbers followed by a string, the numbers will be added before being converted to a string:

```
alert(2 + 2 + '1' ); // "41" and not "221"
```

String concatenation and conversion is a special feature of the binary plus +. Other arithmetic operators work only with numbers and always convert their operands to numbers.

For instance, subtraction and division:

```
alert( 2 - '1' ); // 1
alert( '6' / '2' ); // 3
```

reference https://javascript.info/operators

Answer (score 1):

Because you're concatenating a string (`"The difference is"`) with a number, obtaining a string, and then subtracting a number from it. Use parentheses

```
alert("The Difference is " + (fir-sec));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is due to dynamic type conversion. In your second alert JS engine 1st concatenates `"The Difference is "` and `fir` and then subtracts `sec`. You have to add braces:

`alert("The Difference is " + (fir-sec))`

In all other cases it is ok because `*` and `/` operators have higher priority than `+` operator

Answer (score 0):

Remeber Math's BODMAS theory,

in case of multiplication and division it works and giving you result.

But for substraction, it first does addition.

And finally:

String - Number = NaN